# Complete beginner, trying to list S3 buckets in javascript

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am using some javascript code to retrieve the list of my S3 buckets.
I am login in as an IAM user and I can see the buckets through the AWS Console but the javascript below does not show anything (and does not raise any error).

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');


s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});


s3.listBuckets(function(err, data) {
   if (err) {
      console.log("Error", err);
   } else {
      console.log("Bucket List", data.Buckets);
   }
});
```

PS: I am very rusty in javascript and complete beginner in both AWS SDK and Node.js...

Comment: Strange... I have not done anything but it now works (~10mns later).

Any idea why this happened?

Comment: Above code works for me instantly, maybe you changed something about your environment between then (like node version)

Comment: Not that I know of. However, very happy that it works anyway :-)